# Rewrite allocator

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I want rewrite an allocator in order to trace some statistics about STL containers.
For example I want to find type of containers and elements.
So I wrote the code below.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<class T, class Container, class BaseAllocator = std::allocator<T> >
//template<class T,  class BaseAllocator = std::allocator<T> >
class MyAllocator : public BaseAllocator {
public:
    typedef typename BaseAllocator::pointer pointer;
    typedef typename BaseAllocator::size_type size_type;  

    MyAllocator() throw(): BaseAllocator() {}  // default CTOR

    MyAllocator(const MyAllocator& b) throw() : BaseAllocator(b) {}  // copy ctor

    template <class V>                                            // generic ctor
    MyAllocator(const V& b) throw() : BaseAllocator(b) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }    

   // template <class V>                      // generic copy ctor
   // MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<V>& b) throw() : BaseAllocator(b) {std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;}    

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L    
    MyAllocator(MyAllocator&& b) throw() : BaseAllocator(b) {}
#endif    

    template<class U> struct rebind {
        typedef MyAllocator<U,Container,typename BaseAllocator::template rebind<U>::other> other;
        //typedef MyAllocator<U,typename BaseAllocator::template rebind<U>::other> other;
    };
/*
    template <class U>
    MyAllocator(const typename MyAllocator::template rebind<U>::other& b) throw() : BaseAllocator(b)
    {}
 */
    ~MyAllocator() {}

    pointer allocate(size_type n) {
        std::cout << "allocate" << std::endl;
        pointer r = BaseAllocator::allocate(n);
        return r;
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type n) throw() {
        std::cout << "deallocate" << std::endl;
        BaseAllocator::deallocate(p, n);
    }

#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      template<typename _Up, typename... _Args>
        void construct(_Up* __p, _Args&&... __args)
      { 
        std::cout << "construct c++11 " << typeid(T).name() <<std::endl;
        std::cout << "container c++11 " << typeid(Container).name() <<std::endl;
        ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);        
      }

      template<typename _Up>
      void destroy(_Up* __p) { __p->~_Up(); }
#else
      // _GLIBCXX_RESOLVE_LIB_DEFECTS
      // 402. wrong new expression in [some_] allocator::construct
      void construct(pointer __p, const T& __val)
      {
          std::cout << "construct c++03 " << typeid(T).name() <<std::endl;
          std::cout << "container c++03 " << typeid(Container).name() <<std::endl;
          ::new((void *)__p) T(__val); 
      }
#endif
};

typedef MyAllocator<std::pair<char,int>,std::map<char,int> > allocMap;
typedef std::map<char,int,std::less<char>,allocMap> trackmap;

typedef MyAllocator<double,std::vector<double> > allocVect;
typedef std::vector<double,allocVect> trackvector;


/*
typedef MyAllocator<std::pair<char,int> > allocMap;
typedef std::map<char,int,std::less<char>,allocMap> trackmap;
typedef MyAllocator<double> allocVect;
typedef std::vector<double,allocVect> trackvector;
*/


int main()
{

    std::cout << "*************** MAP ***************" << std::endl;
    trackmap first;
    first['a']=10;
    first.insert(std::pair<char,int>('m',2));
  std::cout << "*************** VECTOR ***************" << std::endl;
  trackvector vett(1,100);
  vett.push_back(4);
  std::cout << "*************** cccccccccccc ***************" << std::endl;   
}
```

I used the typename Container to have information about the kind of container.
I noticed by analyzing the compile errors, that to work, the class needs of a generic constructor. 
To rewrite the allocator, I used as example the definition of the class std::allocator in STL's files (allocator.h, bits/c++allocator.h..). 
In that definition, I did not found a similar CTOR. The class has default ctor, copy ctor and generic copy ctor (to do cast).
Moreover I tested  that if i use the same class without the template argument "Container", the class works fine also without  a generic CTOR.

Someone can explain of the reason ? Why I need of a generic CTOR ?

Said this,  it is sure ? I mean, It is guaranteed that by using this class does the behavior of the STL containers is not modified ?

The code has been compiled by using g++.

Thanks in advance
Andrea

Comment: Does this have to be C++98-compliant? Allocators are so much easier in C++11.

Comment: The short answer is that your allocator needs to meet the allocator requirements of the standard. The long answer involves you reading up what those are.

Comment: Yes I wanted to do a class compliant also with C++98/03

Comment: Hi Kerrek, before to write the class I looked for documentation. On Josuttis'book there is little information on this argument. You have to suggest some good books dealing with the subject

Comment: You seem to have forgotten some template arguments for your "generic copy ctor": `template <class V> MyAllocator(const MyAllocator<V, Container, BaseAllocator>& b)` seems to work fine (removing the "generic ctor").

Comment: Hi dyp, you are great ! :) You have reason. I did not see the error that you have suggested to me. Thanks very much. Your fix is perfect. Thanks a lot